# BigQuery add number to row_number()

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, row-number

I'm new to BigQuery and I would like to ask if there is a possible way to set a starting number for row_number() function using the Legacy SQL. I have tried this code:

```
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by col1) + 20 AS xxx
From tb1
```

but it return this error:

> Error: Encountered " "+" "+ "" at line 2, column 44. Was expecting:

Any answer will be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Your query should work fine.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - as it is - it does not work in BigQuery Legacy SQL :o)

Comment: Consider also [signing up for a preview of the new BigQuery UI](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf6hyfvoWZ8eUbbKWq9fzVfj7ljVyl2SdhtWH038Xrx2eHVrw/viewform), where the query editor defaults to standard SQL.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard that sounds cool :)!! already signed in as well

Comment: btw, thank you @ElliottBrossard - i finally got invite for alpha yesterday

Comment: @WillianFuks - while alpha is in - alpha - so you might still use original BQ UI for some time  - you can use BigQuery Mate where you can set your default SQL - most likely you already using it anyway :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant yeap, indeed :)! standard as default as well lol

Answer (score 4):

If you are new to BigQuery - it is highly recommended to start with BigQuery Standard SQL

And if you willing to follow this advice - below will work without any workarounds (subselect for example in legacy sql)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  20 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS xxx
FROM `project.dataset.tb1`
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.tb1` AS (
  SELECT 1 col1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 111 col1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11 col1
)
SELECT
  col1, 20 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS xxx
FROM `project.dataset.tb1`
```

with output as

```sql
col1    xxx  
1       21   
11      22   
111     23
```

Comment: Thanks! i may have overwhelmed myself in directly using the Legacy SQL due to the demand in my job, thanks though! I'll just update the rest of the query to be compatible with Standard SQL

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . Can you explain what the issue is in legacy SQL?  Expressions and functions usually do mix in that dialect but `row_number()` somehow seems special.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I think having Legacy SQL and Standard SQL implies that Legacy SQL does not meet regular standards and rather was initial tailored for BigQuery dialect of SQL. So it is just matter of implementation. Mayby someone /  Googler from BigQuery Team will be able to answer this question with more specific details :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . You are very knowledgable in the area of BigQuery; I thought you might happen to know.  Strange behavior, but in an outdated dialect.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping with `()`:

```
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by col1)) + 20 AS xxx
From tb1;
```

If not use subquery:

```
SELECT s.xxx + 20 AS xxx
FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by col1) AS xxx
       From tb1) s
```

Comment: it returned this error: `Encountered " "OVER" "OVER "" at line 2, column 17. Was expecting: ")" ...`